# Vapor Fluent OR relationship

Tags: fluent, vapor

I have a two models in Vapor using Fluent as the ORM, one is a `Transaction` and the other is an `Invoice`. The `Transaction` model has the below:

```swift
@OptionalParent(key: "invoice_id")
var invoice: Invoice?
```

So the `invoice` property can be nil or assigned to an `Invoice` model. My question is how do I query for `Transaction`'s where the `invoice` can be `nil` *OR* can be assigned to an `Invoice` where I can check if the `invoice` is active (I have an `isActive` property on the `Invoice` model)?

I tried reading about the below:

https://docs.vapor.codes/fluent/query/

https://forums.swift.org/t/vapor-fluent-query-support-and-xor/32647

So far I'm trying to do like so:

```swift
try? await Transaction.query(on: request.db)
    .with(\.$invoice)
    .sort(\.$dateCreated, .descending)
    .all()
```

I'm then looping through all the `transaction`s and I'm skipping what is not having `isActive` set to `true`.

I also tried the following:

```swift
    let transactions = (try? await Transaction.query(on: request.db)
        .with(\.$invoice)
        .group(.or) { group in
            group
                .filter(\Transaction.$invoice.$id !~ (try inactiveInvoices.map { try $0.requireID() }))
                .filter(\Transaction.$invoice.$id == nil)
        }
        .sort(\.$dateCreated, .descending)
        .all()) ?? []
```

It works...but it has a lot of queries in it. Is there a way to simplify it?

I basically want to check if it's `nil` or if the `isActive` property on `invoice` is `true` from the query itself. Is this possible in Vapor? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution that works! I need to use a *LEFT OUTER JOIN* which can be done by specifying `.left` for the `method` argument on the `join`, like so:

```
let transactions = (try? await Transaction.query(on: request.db)
.with(\.$invoice)
.join(Invoice.self, on: \Transaction.$invoice.$id == \Invoice.$id, method: .left)
.group(.or) { group in
    group
        .filter(Invoice.self, \Invoice.$isActive == true)
        .filter(\.$invoice.$id == nil)
}
.sort(\.$dateCreated, .descending)
.all()) ?? []
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a filter on the original query, after the `with`:

```swift
try? await Transaction.query(on: request.db)
    .with(\.$invoice)
    .group(.or) { group in
        group.filter(\.$invoice == nil).filter(\.$invoice.$isActive == true)
    }
    .sort(\.$dateCreated, .descending)
    .all()
```

I have a feeling the seemingly redundant `== true` is needed here, but can't check at the moment.

Comment: I think I tried that before. I was getting `Value of type 'OptionalParentProperty<Transaction, Invoice>' has no member '$isActive'` for the second `filter` as per the or statement?

Comment: That's odd. I have an almost identical requirement that works.